# Raspberry Pi Zero Stretch /etc/resolv.conf DNS problem

Tags: raspbian-stretch, dns, apt

I cannot use `apt` update as every reboot my 
`sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf` file resets to the below

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search home
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I have tried to change the `nameserver` to a proper DNS but it resets every reboot? How can I fix this?

Comment: The file is automatically generated. If this is missing it indicates some problem in your networking setup. You should specify what you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the first line of `/etc/resolv.conf` it is generated by resolvconf. If you want to set a static domain name server you have to uncomment in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` the line:

```
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1
```

and set it to your name server and reboot. Maybe you have also to stop asking for a domain name server from your dhcp server. You can try to modify the line:

```
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
```

to

```
option domain_name, domain_search, host_name
```

Comment: No. This file does not exist, and creating it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @DanielF Of course does it exist. This is an accepted answer. As seen from the tags of the question we are talking about `raspbian-stretch`. So please use a default unmodified image from it and you will find `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf` because **dhcpcd** is the default networking management for Raspbian. If you have a problem with your setup then please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the following file:

   $ sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
2. Put your nameserver list in the file like those:

   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
3. Update resolvconf with the following command:

   $ sudo resolvconf -u

Comment: The file doesn't exist and I cannot create it either with sudo or directly as root

Comment: I also know the trick with editing /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base on my Ubuntu Server machines, but Raspbians resolvconf seems to work different. Even creating the missing *resolv.conf.d* directory and *base* directory and setting the same file permissions than on my Ubuntu permissions did not do the trick.